# Angular 5 Interface variable not assignable to type issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I am using Angular 5 and have created a very simple Interface file:

```
export interface INavbar {
  title: string;
}
```

Then I imported it into my .ts file:

and tried to add a value to the variable:

```
title: INavbar = 'myTitle';
```

The problem is that I'm getting error:

```
Type: "myTitle" is not assignable to type 'INavbar'
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: `title: INavbar` means title is type of INavbar, while its real tyoe is string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you write

```
title = 'myTitle';
```

no matter the type of the variable, you provide a string. This means `title` is a string.

If you want to create an object implementing your interface, you should do something like this :

```
navbar: INavbar = {
  title: 'myTitle'
};
```